# Multiprocessing Pool not getting all cores

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a code that requires some parallelization for which I used the Python's `multiprocessing` module, and in particular, the `Pool` class. The relevant part of the code where parallelization takes place looks something like this

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

@jit( nopython=True )
def numba_product( a, b ):
        
    a_len = len(a)
    b_len = len(b)
    n     = len( a[0,:] )    
    c_res   = np.empty( (  a_len*b_len, n ), dtype=np.complex128 ) 
    c_count = 0  
    for i in range(a_len):
        for j in range( b_len ):            
            c_res[ c_count , : ] = np.multiply( a[i,:], b[ j, : ]  )          
            c_count += 1
            
    return c_res

def do_some_computations( shared_object, index ):

    d  = shared_object.get_dictionary_1()
            
    some_numpy_array_1 = shared_object.get_numpy_array_1( index ) #this gets a numpy array from 
                                                                  # shared object attribute, i.e.,
                                                                  # from shared_object class 
                                                                  # definition, the method returns
                                                                  # "self.the_array" attribute that
                                                                  # belongs to shared object, see 
                                                                  # dummy version of class definition 
                                                                  # below            
    mask_array_1       = shared_object.get_mask_array_1() # this gets a mask for the specified array        
    filtered_array_1   = some_numpy_array_1[ mask_array_1] #note that this defines a local new array, 
                                                           # but shouldn't modify some_numpy_array_1 
                                                           # ( I believe ) 
    
    s_keys             = shared_object.get_keys_for_index( index ) #gets the keys corresponding to 
                                                                   #that index to create a new array        
    
    v   = np.array( [ d1[ x ] for x in  s_keys  ] )

    final_result = numba_product( filtered_array_1, v )  # 
   

def pool_worker_function( index, args ):    
    shared_object = args[0] 
    result = do_some_computations( shared_object, index ) 
    return result    
        
    
def parallel_exec( shared_object, N ):
    number_processors      = mp.cpu_count()
    number_used_processors = number_processors - 1

    #try pool map method with a READ-ONLY object that is "shared_object".
    # This object contains two big dictionaries from which values are retrieved, 
    # and various NumPy arrays of considerable dimension           
    from itertools import repeat      

    pool    = mp.Pool( processes = number_used_processors )       
     
    a = list( np.linspace( 0, N, N ) )          
    
    args = ( shared_object, )     
    number_tasks = number_used_processors  
      
    n_chunck = int( ( len(a) - 1 )/number_tasks )
             
    result = pool.starmap( pool_worker_function, zip( a, repeat( args ) ), chunksize = n_chunck)              
    pool.close()        
    pool.join()           
    return result
```

**THE PROBLEM**:

The problem I am having is that when I run it under Unix OS, on a 32-core system, I only observe few cores being working on the parallelization... As far as I understand, Unix provides automatic `os.fork()` as *copy-on-write*, which means that IF my shared_object is not modified during the calls, the parallelization should take place without extra memory consumption, and all cores should execute their tasks separately? Here is a snapshot of what I see when the program reaches the parallelization part:

[image: Resulting CPU usage from top command]

These is puzzling me and I have made sure that the total number of cores provided by cpu.count() is 32. Another thing that I observe is that throughout the parallelization, the amount of free memory decreases continuously from ~84 GiB available to ~59 GiB. This hints probably that copies of the "shared_object" class are being created with each process, therefore making a copy of all the dictionaries and NumPy arrays that the class contains. I would like to circumvent this issue; I would like to use all cores for the parallelization, but honestly I have no idea of what is going on here.

The code is expected to run in the Unix machine of 32 cores, but my own laptop has Windows OS, and here is a snapshot of what I see on Windows when I launch it ( although for what I have read, Windows does not support `os.fork()` method, so no surprise on the high memory consumption I guess ? ).

[image: CPU performance on Windows]

As you can see, calls to the OS( in red ) occupy a very high % of the CPU usage. This seems to be the case also in the snapshot shown above for the Linux case.

Finally, I want to stress that the class "shared_object" has the following form:

```
class shared_object():

    def __init__(): pass
    
    def store_dictionaries_and_arrays( dict_1, dict_2, array_1, array_2, ...  ):
        
        self.dict_1 = dict_1
        self.dict_2 = dict_2
        self.array_1 = array_1
        # same for all other arguments passed
    def get_dictionary_1():
        return self.dict_1
    def get_numpy_array_1():
        return self.array_1
```

but for many more attributes, therefore many more "get" methods. This is a very big data container, and therefore I would like to expect no copies of it when executing the parallelization, since attributes should only be accessed but not modified, what am I missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated, this has been hitting me for long time now... Many thanks!

Comment: I'd guess that your `shared_object` is being copied repeatedly into each child process.  maybe you could pass it to `initargs` when you create the pool, or use a `Manager` to just have one copy in the parent (which would serialize access).

Comment: Thank you for the answer; yes that seems to be the case, but then why is this happening only in some CPU's while the others remain idle? This shouldn't be the case if the shared_object is not modified during the calls, and all CPU's should run

Comment: how is python supposed to know that `shared_object` isn't modified? you've not said that anywhere in the code and determining that would basically require solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  if you know it's read-only and you only care about running in Unix I suppose you could put it into a global variable before creating the `Pool` and just let the child processes pick it up from there

Comment: As far as I understand it, in the os.fork() multiprocessing, all child processes will inherit "by default" a copy of the father's memory. My question has to do more with how certain operations within the class can result in modifications; for instance, the dictionary assignment  d = class.get_dict() using the method, I would assume this does not alter the object. However, it is difficult to tell whether Python "maybe" interprets this assignment as something that can result into any modifications. You propose writing "global shared_object" before initializing the object in the code right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your comments, I think you just want to do something like this:

```
def pool_worker_function(index, args):
    return do_some_computations(_shared_hack, index)

def parallel_exec(shared_object, N):
    global _shared_hack
    _shared_hack = shared_object

    # it'll use ncores processes by default
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        return pool.map(pool_worker_function, range(N))
```

i.e. save the `shared_object` somewhere global and let the child processes pick it up as they need it.

you're doing lots of weirdness setting things up which I've stripped out including setting up a list of `chuncks` which weren't used anywhere.  I've also switched to using `range` as you were also using `list(np.linspace(0, N, N))` to set up some indexes which seems broken. e.g., `N=4` would give you `[0, 1.333, 2.667, 4]` which doesn't look like something I'd want to index an array with

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, and sorry for the mesh in the code;I forgot to erase some unnecesary parts. Declaring _shared_hack as global in the module where multiprocessing occurs, how does this prevent multiple access from all different processes onto the object? If I understand correctly, there should be only one instance of the object now that belongs to "globals", can I expect to have shared memory here or not? What if the code actually does modify the class in some sense? (which it shouldn't) Isn't this a bit problematic then?

Comment: maybe read about the semantics of [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)).  each child gets their own (mutable) copy of everything, they just diverge from the parent when changes are made.  hence any changes made in any child process aren't seen by the parent, and any changes made by the parent after the fork aren't seen by children

Comment: This actually solved the problem, now all CPUs are taken to perform the calculation, thanks!